# Inserting a figure in a memoir document

Tags: memoir, booklet

For the very fisrt time, I am using the document class memoir to prepare a booklet. Everything was going pretty well until I have to insert a picture to finish my task[image: my fig]

Note that my figure is loaded on Overleaf, I opened the figure environment, but If I recompile, my page is cutted as If I was typing in a regular A4 sheet of paper

[image: figure 2]

here is my MWE

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% http://latexbr.blogspot.com.br
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[all]{xy}

 \settypeblocksize{5.5in}{4in}{*}
 \addtolength{\textheight}{\onelineskip}
 \setlrmargins{2in}{*}{*} % margem esquerda
 \setulmargins{3in}{*}{*} % margem superior
 \checkandfixthelayout

% booklet
\usepackage[print,1to1]{booklet} 
\pagespersignature{68} % coloque multiplos de 4
\setpdftargetpages % para impressao de pdf

% reposiciona as paginas para impressao
 \ifprintoption
   \special{!TeXDict begin /landplus90{true}store end}
   \special{!TeXDict begin <</Tumble true>> setpagedevice end}
 \fi

%-----criaçao de títulos para topicos
\newtheorem{definicao}{Definição}
\newtheorem{exer}{$\checkmark$ Exercícios}
\newtheorem{proposicao}{Proposição}
\newtheorem{lema}{Lema}
\newtheorem{corolario}{Corolário}
\newtheorem{postulado}{Postulado}
\newtheorem{teorema}{Teorema}
\newtheorem{exemplo}{Exemplo}
\newtheorem{obs}{Observação}
\newtheorem*{texto}{}

%--------------------definição de comandos
\newcommand{\dem}{{ \noindent \it Demonstração:\\ }}
\newcommand{ \cqd}{$\hspace*{\stretch{1}} \square$\\}
\newcommand{ \aj}{  \vspace*{-2ex} \noindent}
\newcommand{ \sol}{ \emph{Solução:}\\}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
{\large \textbf{SINEPEM}}\\
{\footnotesize SIMPÓSIO NACIONAL SOBRE O ENSINO E PESQUISA DA  MATEMÁTICA\\
 NO CONTEXTO DA EDUCAÇÃO, CIÊNCIA E TECNOLOGIA}\\
 \textbf{IFPA}
\end{center}

\vspace*{25ex}

\begin{center}
\vspace*{3ex}
{\Large \textbf{O USO DA ÁLGEBRA NA}}\\
\vspace*{1ex}
{\Large  \textbf{CONSTRUÇÃO DE CÓDIGOS}}\\
\vspace*{1ex}
{\Large \textbf{CORRETORES DE ERROS}}
\end{center}

\vspace*{25ex}

\begin{center}
ORGANIZADOR\\
Demetrius Gonçalves de Araújo\\
BELÉM - PARÁ\\
Maio de 2019\\
\end{center}

\newpage

\vspace*{-2cm}

\begin{center}
\hspace*{-3cm} \textbf{NAZARÉ BEZERRA}
\end{center}

\vspace*{30ex}

\begin{center}
\hspace*{-3cm} {\large MINICURSO}\\
\vspace*{3ex}
\hspace*{-3cm} {\Large \textbf{O USO DA ÁLGEBRA NA}}\\
\vspace*{1ex}
\hspace*{-3cm} {\Large  \textbf{CONSTRUÇÃO DE CÓDIGOS}}\\
\vspace*{1ex}
\hspace*{-3cm} {\Large \textbf{CORRETORES DE ERROS}}\\
\vspace*{3ex}
\hspace*{-3cm} {\large Notas de Aula}\\
\end{center}

\vspace*{30ex}

\begin{center}
\hspace*{-3cm} Belém - Pará\\
\hspace*{-3cm} Maio de 2019\\
\end{center}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\pagestyle{headings}

\tableofcontents

\chapter*{Prefácio}

\hspace*{3ex}
Inúmeras são  as tarefas do nosso cotidiano que usam dados digitais, tais como armazenamento de dados em computadores, uso de telefonia móvel, aparelhos de armazenamento de dados (CD, DVD), comunicações via satélite, processamento de imagens digitais, internet, radio, etc.

Em todos esses casos, cada informação
é codificada como uma sequência de dígitos binários, processo esse chamado de \emph{codificação}. E é essa sequência de dígitos que é armazenada ou transmitida. Ao se acessar a informação armazenada ou recebê-la em uma transmissão, usa-se o processo inverso - chamado de \emph{decodificação} -
 que converte a sequência de dígitos binários na informação original.

 Um dos principais problemas dessa técnica é a ocorrência de \emph{ruídos},  decorrentes de diversas fontes, que causam alterações nos dados,
fazendo com que a informação recuperada seja diferente da original. Esses \emph{erros} comprometem  a confiabilidade do processo. Uma forma de contornar esse problema é acrescentar alguma redundância em cada  dado  a ser armazenado ou transmitido.

Grosso modo, pode-se dizer que um \textbf{Código Corretor de Erros} é um processo pelo qual acrescentam-se dados adicionais a cada informação que se quer armazenar ou transmitir, de modo que na recuperação dessa informação, sejamos capazes de \textbf{detectar} se houve erro na transmis\-são/armazenamento e, caso afirmativo, \textbf{corrigir} o erro, recuperando a informação inicial.

A Teoria dos Códigos Corretores de Erros teve  início  no final da década de 1940, tendo como pioneiros Richard W. Hamming,
C.E. Shannon e Marcel J. E. Golay.
Nas décadas de 1940 e 1950, essa teoria foi essencialmente desenvolvida pelos matemáticos. Hoje, devido suas múltiplas aplicações, é um campo de pesquisa que desperta grande interesse, sendo estudada na Matemática, na Computação, na Engenharia Elétrica, dentre outras.

Neste minicurso faremos uma breve  introdução à Teoria dos Códigos Corretores de Erros, apresentando os mais simples, que são os Códigos Li\-neares, enfatizando como os conceitos da Álgebra, em particular da Álgebra Linear, são úteis na construção desses códigos.

No Capítulo 1 apresentamos os conceitos básicos da Teoria de Códigos Corretores e no Capítulo 2, após  relembrarmos os conceitos de Corpo, Espaço Vetorial e Transformação Linear, definimos Código Linear, ilustrando com  alguns exemplos. No Capítulo 3, faremos uso das propriedades de espaço vetorial dos códigos lineares para desenvolver  um algoritmo  para  a detecção e correção de erros.

Estas notas de aula tem como principal fonte de referência o livro \emph{Códigos Corretores de Erros}, de Abramo Hefez e Maria Lucia T. VilLela, publicado pelo IMPA em 2008.

\chapter{Códigos Corretores de Erros}

\section{Introdução}

\section*{O que é um Código Corretor de Erros?}
É um  processo pelo qual acrescentam-se dados adicionais a cada informação que se quer transmitir ou armazenar, de modo que na recuperação dessas informações, se possa \textbf{detectar e corrigir erros} decorrentes do processo de transmissão ou armazenamento.

\section*{A utilização}
  Os código corretores de erros são utilizados sempre que fazemos uso de informações digitalizadas, tais como telefonia móvel, aparelhos de armazenamento de dados (CD, DVD), comunicações via satélite, processamento de imagens digitais, internet, radio, etc.

\section*{O surgimento}
A Teoria dos Códigos Corretores de Erros teve início no final da década de 1940, tendo como pioneiros Richard W. Hamming,
C.E. Shannon  (ambos dos \emph{Laboratórios Bell}) e Marcel J. E. Golay (\emph{Signal Corps Enginnering Laboratories}).
Nas décadas de 1940 e 1950, essa teoria foi essencialmente estudada pelos matemáticos. Hoje é um campo de pesquisa que desperta grande interesse, sendo pesquisada na Matemática, na Computação, na Engenharia Elétrica, na Estatística, dentre outras.

\section*{Estrutura de um Código Corretor de Erros}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=0.8]{cce01.jpg}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:my_label}
\end{figure}

\section*{Álgebra x Códigos Corretores}

A Álgebra age como uma ferramenta nas seguintes etapas do processo:\\
$(i)$ na transformação do código da fonte em código de canal;\\
$(ii)$ na detecção e  correção dos erros presentes nos dados recebidos;\\
$(iii)$ na decodificação do código de canal em código da fonte.

\section{Conceitos Básicos}

Sejam $A$ um conjunto finito e não vazio, chamado  \textbf{alfabeto}, $n \ge 1$ um inteiro arbitrário
e
$$A^n = \{ (a_1, a_2, ..., a_n) \mid a_1, a_2, ..., a_n \in A \}$$
o conjunto de todas as $n$-uplas de elementos de $A$.



\section*{Disco e Esfera em um Código}

\begin{definicao}
Dados $\mathbf{a} \in A^n$ e um inteiro $t > 0$, definimos
 o \textbf{disco} de centro em  $\mathbf{a}$ e raio $t$, como o conjunto:
$$D(a, t) := \{ x \in A^n  \mid d(a, x) \le t \}.$$
\end{definicao}

\chapter{Códigos Lineares}

Antes de definirmos Código Linear, faremos uma breve revisão nos conceitos de Corpo, Espaço Vetorial e Transformação Linear, necessários na construção desses códigos.

\section{Corpo}


\begin{definicao}  Um \textbf{corpo} é um conjunto não vazio $F$ munido de
duas operações:\\
\\
\hspace*{10ex} \textbf{Adição}   \hspace{24ex}  \textbf{Multiplicação}\\
\hspace*{4ex} \begin{tabular}{lllccclcc}
 $+$ \, : &  $F \times F$    & $\to$ & $F$ &    \hspace{7ex}          & $.$ \, : &  $F \times F$ & $\to$ & $F$\\
   &  $(a, b)$    & $\to$ & $a+b$ &    \hspace{7ex}          &  &  $(a, b) $ & $\to$ & $a.b$\\
\end{tabular}

\section{Espaço Vetorial}

\begin{definicao}  Um \textbf{espaço vetorial sobre um corpo $F$} é um
conjunto não vazio $V$, munido de duas operações:\\
\\
\hspace*{10ex} \textbf{Adição}   \hspace{20ex}  \textbf{Multiplicação}\\
\hspace*{4ex} \begin{tabular}{lcccccccc}
 $+$: &  $V \times V$    & $\to$ & $V$ &    \hspace{5ex}          & $.$: &  $F \times V$ & $\to$ & $V$\\
   &  $(u, v)$    & $\to$ & $u + v$ &    \hspace{5ex}          &  &  $(\alpha, u) $ & $\to$ & $\alpha u$\\
\\
\end{tabular}


\chapter{Decodificação no Código Linear}

\section{Introdução}

 Como já dito,  na essência os códigos corretores trabalham com o acréscimo de dados, objetivando a  detecção e a correção de erros decorrentes da manipulação desses dados. Porém, essa redundância  de informação tem um custo.  Um dos desafios da teoria de códigos é fazer esse acréscimo  de forma eficiente e ao menor custo possível.


\section{Matriz Geradora do Código}

No produto matricial  em  (3.2), quando $(x_1, x_2)$ assume todos os valores possíveis, isto é, percorre  os elementos de



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%BIBLIOGRAFIA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\normalsize{

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Bibliografia}

\begin{thebibliography}{99}

\bibitem{t2} FIRER, Marcelo. \emph{Códigos Corretores de Erros - Notas de Aula}. UNICAMP, 2007.

\bibitem{t1} HEFEZ, Abramo e VILLELA, Maria Lúcia T. \emph{Códigos Corretores de Erros}. IMPA - Série de Computação e Matemática, 2008.

\bibitem{t2} MILIES, César Polcino. \emph{Breve Introdução à Teoria dos Códigos Corretores de Erros}. Colóquio de Matemática da Região Centro Oeste - SBM, 2009.

\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Please, does anyone have suggestions? Thanks in advance for your attetion

Comment: it is much better if you show a complete small example document as text (`{}` in the editor) not images of the code, however it looks from `\special{!TeXDict be..` that you are using latex+dvips not pdflatex. dvips can not include jpg files.

Comment: The log will show an error message I assume?

Comment: Class memoir Error: Font command \it is not supported.

See the memoir class documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.1455 \dem
           
Use \textit, or \itshape{...}, or the oldfontcommands option

Overfull \vbox (1.07225pt too high) has occurred while \output is active []

 main.tex, line 114
Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph at lines 114--118

Comment: these are the errors...I think that they don't have anything to do, but it is also possible that I am not understanding

Comment: You can force `memoir` to use old formatting comments, such as `\it`, even if I think it's not the main issue here.

Comment: scale=0.6 of what ?

Comment: Please provide a compilable MWE that shows the problem. Perhaps it is due to the size of the figure or the file format or ...

Comment: @PeterWilson What is MWE? If I use "\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}" + "\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}",  the figure is appears correctly, but it is not good for me because a I need to print this document in a booklet

Comment: @MarcosPaulo MWE = Minimal Working Example. Code from `\documentclass   ` through to `\end{document}` that exhibits the problem and that we can process. Use, for example, the `lipsum` package for producing reams of text.

Comment: @PeterWilson just added a MWE

Comment: @MarcosPaulo, your document just doesn't compile. `\normalsize{` is not closed by `}`. You can format your code indenting it with 4 spaces (see the box above as you write). It's **not** minimal, either.

Comment: @MarcosPaulo, "it is not good for me because a I need to print this document in a booklet" -- but isn't the `booklet` package doing all the work here, instead of the `memoir` class?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you printed a simple document (MWE):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[outermargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{pdfpages}


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\blinddocument


 \end{document}
```

Now, to create a booklet with the package `pdfpages`, you only need to set it with the produced .pdf:

%here is my MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[outermargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} \usepackage[brazil]{babel} 
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[final]{pdfpages}


\begin{document}
%\tableofcontents

%\blinddocument
\includepdf[pages=-, signature=4,landscape]{doc.pdf}




 \end{document}
```

(For other options, see the `pdfpages` manual.)

Other packages and content are irrelevant insofar as what you want is a booklet.

Comment: Agreed This is by far the simplest solution the OP combination of a4Portrait then trying to work landscape with all the conflicting boundaries is completely done away with by here simply importing at an effective page scale of 0.71 or whatever you set by geometry